Webserver on Kubernetes works with one replica, but randomly fails with more than one replicas
I deployed a Kubernetes deployment with 3 pod replicas using the following yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

The command I used was kubectl create -f nginx-deployment.yaml
I then deployed a NodePort service using the following yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ngnix-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80

The command I used was kubectl create -f nginx-service.yaml
The problem I'm facing is that I am having intermittent issues with the pods: when I send requests to the webservers deployed at the pods, they frequently timeout.
However, if I use only one replica, I do not have such issues.
I use wget to issue the requests, but with more than 1 replicas, the  requests randomly fail. On average, about 50% of the requests fail.
I've tried:

Adding readiness checks to the pods. The pods come up as 'running' even with the readiness checks.
Logging in to the pods and using curl to send a request to localhost. This works for all the pods as well.

What could be going wrong? I'd appreciate any and all help!
